# Google Cloud components not being enabled

Tags: docker, travis-ci, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to get an automatic build going via Travis-CI to google cloud, but when I'm trying to run "gcloud docker any_command", I get the message

```
ERROR: (gcloud) Invalid choice: 'docker'. Did you mean 'config'?
```

and when I try to install docker with "gcloud components install docker" I get

```
You cannot perform this action because the component manager has been 
disabled for this installation.  If you would like get the latest 
version of the Google Cloud SDK, please see our main download page at:
  https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/
ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) The component manager is disabled for this installation
```

This is my .travis.yml file -

```
sudo: required
language: python
python:
  - "2.7"
deploy:
  provider: gae
  keyfile: client-secret.json
  project: galvanic-being-138423
notifications:
  email: false
services:
  - docker
cache:
  directories:
  - $HOME/google-cloud-sdk/
env:
- GAE_PYTHONPATH=${HOME}/.cache/google_appengine PATH=$PATH:${HOME}/google-cloud-sdk/bin
  PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${GAE_PYTHONPATH} CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1
before_install:
- openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_3ae578884e67_key -iv $encrypted_3ae578884e67_iv
  -in credentials.tar.gz.enc -out credentials.tar.gz -d
- rm -rf ${HOME}/google-cloud-sdk/
- curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash;
- ls -l ${HOME}/google-cloud-sdk/bin
- which gcloud
- gcloud --version
- if [ ! -d "${GAE_PYTHONPATH}" ]; then python scripts/fetch_gae_sdk.py $(dirname
  "${GAE_PYTHONPATH}"); fi
- if [ ! -d ${HOME}/google-cloud-sdk ]; then curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash;
  fi

install:
- pip install pyOpenSSL
- sudo rm -rf /opt/google-cloud-sdk/
- export CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1
- export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES=1
- tar -xzf credentials.tar.gz
- mkdir -p lib
- gcloud auth activate-service-account galvanic-being-138423@appspot.gserviceaccount.com --key-file client-secret.json
- gcloud config set project galvanic-being-138423
- gcloud config set compute/zone europe-west1-c
- gcloud config set container/cluster example-cluster
- ssh-keygen -q -N "" -f ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine
- gcloud init galvanic-being-138423
- gcloud components update
- gcloud components install docker
- curl -L  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases/download/v1.3.3/kubernetes.tar.gz > kubernetes.tar.gz 
- tar -xf kubernetes.tar.gz
- sudo cp kubernetes/platforms/linux/amd64/kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
- sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kubectl
- docker pull wordpress:latest
- docker build -t gcr.io/galvanic-being-138423/wordpress-testing:v1 docker/
- gcloud docker push gcr.io/galvanic-being-138423/wordpress-testing:v1
- kubectl config set-cluster example-cluster --server=http://galvanic-being-138423.appspot.com
- kubectl config set-context example-cluster --cluster=example-cluster
- kubectl config use-context example-cluster
- kubectl run wordpress-testing --image=gcr.io/galvanic-being-138423/wordpress-testing:v1 --port=80
```

EDIT:

gcloud --version gives:

```
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.37
bq 2.0.18
bq-nix 2.0.18
compute 2014.11.25
core 2014.11.25
core-nix 2014.11.25
dns 2014.11.25
gcutil 1.16.5
gcutil-nix 1.16.5
gsutil 4.6
gsutil-nix 4.6
sql 2014.11.25
```

Comment: What version of gcloud do you have? `docker` should be included by default; it's not a separate component.

Comment: gcloud --version prints out this in Travis: Google Cloud SDK 0.9.37

Comment: You are using a pretty old version of the Google Cloud SDK. In that version, the docker command may have been under preview. So try `gcloud preview docker`.

Alternatively, you can install the latest version of the SDK by following the instructions at: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/.